# Magento2 - How to get product additional options from quote_items_options using product id

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have successfully saved product additional options in **"quote_items_options"** table .
Now I want to retrieve those options using **product_id.**

Can anyone help me how can I get additional options?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get product wise additional option using below code. (Do not use **Objectmanager** directly if the code works then change dependency use via construct)

```
$productId = 68;
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
 //This return something
 $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
   foreach ($items as $item) {
     $customOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
       $row = $customOptions->getData();
       if($row['item_id'] == $productId){
         print_r($row['value']);
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Option\CollectionFactory $quoteItemCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory = $quoteItemCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|void
 */
public function execute()
{
    $quoteItemCollection = $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory->create();
    $quoteItemCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', 135);
    print_r($quoteItemCollection->getData()); 


}
```